# Amazon SP-API Listings API putListingsItem How To Update price and quantity? Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am using [amazon-sp-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-sp-api) (JavaScript client for the Amazon Selling Partner API) but this is not limited to this client.  All I want to do is use the Amazon SP-API Listings API's [putListingsItem call](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2020-09-01-reference#putlistingsitem) to update the price and quantity of an item I have listed.

**productType**

According to the [ListingsItemPutRequest](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2020-09-01-reference#listingsitemputrequest) docs, `productType` and `attributes` are required for this call.

Firstly, to obtain the correct `productType` value, you are supposed to search for a product definitions type using the [Product Type Definitions API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-type-definitions-api-v2020-09-01-reference). So, I do that, and call [searchDefinitionsProductTypes](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-type-definitions-api-v2020-09-01-reference#searchdefinitionsproducttypes), just to discover my product has no matching product type.

Ultimately, I gave the value `PRODUCT` for `productType` field. Using `PRODUCT`, I made the `getDefinitionsProductType` call and got an object containing an array of `propertyNames`, shown below:

```
            "propertyNames": [
                "skip_offer",
                "fulfillment_availability",
                "map_policy",
                "purchasable_offer",
                "condition_type",
                "condition_note",
                "list_price",
                "product_tax_code",
                "merchant_release_date",
                "merchant_shipping_group",
                "max_order_quantity",
                "gift_options",
                "main_offer_image_locator",
                "other_offer_image_locator_1",
                "other_offer_image_locator_2",
                "other_offer_image_locator_3",
                "other_offer_image_locator_4",
                "other_offer_image_locator_5"
            ]
        },
```

On seeing this, I decide `list_price` and `fulfillment_availability` must be the **price** and **quantity** and then try using these in my code below.

**attributes**

The `attributes` value is also required.  However, their current docs show no clear example of what to put for these values, which are where I must put price and quantity somewhere.

I found this link about [patchListingsItem](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/1714) and tried to implement that below but got an error.

code:

```
// trying to update quantity... failed.

        a.response =  await a.sellingPartner.callAPI({
            operation:'putListingsItem',
            path:{
              sellerId: process.env.SELLER_ID,
              sku: `XXXXXXXXXXXX`
            },
            query: {
              marketplaceIds: [ `ATVPDKIKX0DER` ]
            },
            body: {
              "productType": `PRODUCT`
              "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
              "attributes": {
                    "fulfillment_availability": {
                        "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
                                "quantity": 4,
                                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                            }
                        }
          });

        console.log( `a.response: `, a.response )
```

error:

```
{
    "sku": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "status": "INVALID",
    "submissionId": "34e1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "4000001",
            "message": "The provided value for 'fulfillment_availability' is invalid.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "attributeName": "fulfillment_availability"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried using list_price :

```
// list_price attempt... failed.


        a.response =  await a.sellingPartner.callAPI({
            operation:'putListingsItem',
            path:{
              sellerId: process.env.SELLER_ID,
              sku: `XXXXXXXXXXXX`
            },
            query: {
              marketplaceIds: [ `ATVPDKIKX0DER` ]
            },
            body: {
              "productType": `PRODUCT`
              "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
              "attributes": {
                    "list_price": {
                        "Amount": 90,
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD"
                    }
          });

        console.log( `a.response: `, a.response )
```

Error (this time seems I got warmer... maybe?):

```
{
    "sku": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "status": "INVALID",
    "submissionId": "34e1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "4000001",
            "message": "The provided value for 'list_price' is invalid.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "attributeName": "list_price"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do you correctly specify the list_price or the quantity so this call will be successful?

Just tryin to update a single item's price and quantity.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for this side of things is terrible. I've managed to get some of it through a fair bit of trial and error though.

Fulfillment and Availability can be set with this block of JSON

```
"fulfillment_availability": [{
"fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT", 
"quantity": "9999", 
"lead_time_to_ship_max_days": "5"
}]
```

and List price gets set, oddly, with this block. I'm still trying to find out how to set the List Price with Tax however.

```
"purchasable_offer": [{
"currency": "GBP",
"our_price": [{"schedule": [{"value_with_tax": 285.93}]}],
"marketplace_id": "A1F83G8C2ARO7P"
}]
```

Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: Did you succeded? I'm stuck! I always get: "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Request has missing or invalid parameters and cannot be parsed.",
      "details": ""
    }

Comment: Yeah, the docs caused a lot of frustrated swearing and sighing over here. How come, a company that big sucks so much at writing clear and useful documentation? Or is this intentional somehow?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried patch then?

I could update product quantity with this json:

```json
{
    "productType":"BLANKET",
    "patches":[
    {
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"/attributes/fulfillment_availability",
        "value": [
            {
                "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
                "quantity": 33
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

patching on the endpoint:
`{{host}}/listings/2021-08-01/items/:sellerID/:sku?marketplaceIds={{marketplaceid}}`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my exact put_listings function using the saleweaver spapi wrapper... hopefully the json should be similar to what you're doing regardless.

@throttle_retry(tries=10, delay=5, rate=2.5)

def put_listings(new_sku, asin, lead_time, price, condition, amazonMainProductType, category, isFBA, shippingName, quantity, marketplace, moq=None, conditionNote=None, **kwargs):

credentials = load_credentials()

```
# Prepare the body data for the API call
body_data = {
"productType": amazonMainProductType,
"requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
"sku": new_sku,
"summaries": [
    {
        "marketplaceId": marketplace,
        "asin": asin,
        "productType": category,
        "conditionType": condition,
        "status": ["DISCOVERABLE", "BUYABLE"],
        # "itemName": "Fortnite Series 2 Trading Card Fat Pack"
    }
],
"attributes": {
    "purchasable_offer": [
        {
            "our_price": [
                {
                    "schedule": [
                        {
                            "value_with_tax": price
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ],
    "product_tax_code": [
        {
            "value": "A_GEN_TAX",
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ],
    "merchant_suggested_asin": [
        {
            "value": asin,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ],
    "condition_type": [
        {
            "value": condition,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ],
    "merchant_shipping_group": [
        {
            "value": "legacy-template-id",
            "enumNames": shippingName,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ],
    "list_price": [
        {
            "value": price,
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
        }
    ],
    "fulfillment_availability": [
        {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
            "quantity": quantity,
            "lead_time_to_ship_max_days": lead_time,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ]
},
"issues": [],
"offers": [
    {
        "marketplaceId": marketplace,
        "offerType": "B2C",
        "price": {
            "amount": price,
            "isFulfilledByAmazon": isFBA
                                    }
    }
],

"procurement": []
```

}

```
if moq is not None:
    body_data["attributes"]["max_order_quantity"] = [
        {
            "value": moq,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ]

if conditionNote:
    body_data["attributes"]["condition_note"] = [
        {
            "value": conditionNote,
            "marketplace_id": marketplace

        }
    ]

# If fulfillmentChannelCode indicates FBA (i.e., "AmazonNA"), 
    # we remove both the merchant_shipping_group and quantity from the attributes
if isFBA == "true":
    # Change fulfillment_channel_code to "AMAZON_NA"
    body_data["attributes"]["fulfillment_availability"][0] = {
        "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
        "marketplace_id": marketplace,
        "conditionType": condition,
        "isFulfilledByAmazon": isFBA
    }

    # Remove merchant_shipping_group
    if "merchant_shipping_group" in body_data["attributes"]:
        del body_data["attributes"]["merchant_shipping_group"]

    # Add batteries related information
    body_data["attributes"]["batteries_required"] = [
        {
            "value": False,  # Set to False as batteries are not required
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ]

    # Set 'supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation' to 'not_applicable'
    body_data["attributes"]["supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation"] = [
        {
            "value": "not_applicable",
            "marketplace_id": marketplace
        }
    ]
else:
    # Keep fulfillment_channel_code as "DEFAULT" (or set it explicitly)
    body_data["attributes"]["fulfillment_availability"][0]["fulfillment_channel_code"] = "DEFAULT"
    # Set quantity based on the provided value
    body_data["attributes"]["fulfillment_availability"][0]["quantity"] = quantity


# dubugging line for api information #
# print(body_data) 
default_kwargs = {
    'marketplaceIds': marketplace,
    'sellerId': os.getenv("SELLER_ID"),
    'sku': new_sku,
    'body': body_data  # Pass the body data here
}

merged_kwargs = {**default_kwargs, **kwargs}

# dubugging line for api information #
# print("Sending the following data to put_listings_item:", merged_kwargs)

order_client = ListingsItems(credentials=credentials)
try:
    listing_items = order_client.put_listings_item(**merged_kwargs)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

# dubugging line for api information #
    # Print the full response
# print("Full API Response:")
# print(f"{listing_items}")

# Check the status of the response
status = listing_items.payload.get('status')
errors = listing_items.payload.get('errors')

if status == "ACCEPTED":
    print(f"{new_sku} - Listing Accepted at Amazon")
else:
    print(f"Error: {status}")
if errors == "NONE":
    print("No Errors")
else:
    print(f"Error: {errors}")
# print(listing_items)

return listing_items
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use this to update prices and quantity
Note -Changes will take around 20 min

```
{
    "productType": "PRODUCT",
      "patches": [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/attributes/fulfillment_availability",
          "value": [
            {
              "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
              "quantity": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            "op":
            "replace",
            "path":
            "/attributes/purchasable_offer",
            "value": [{
                "marketplace_id": "APJ6JRA9NG5V4",
                "currency": "EUR",
                "our_price": [{ "schedule": [{ "value_with_tax": 35.99 }] }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**